# Dynamic AppBar of Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have to change AppBar appearance and items dynamically (by tapping on another UI elements).
What is the best approach?

I tested several methods. For example,

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: StreamBuilder(
          stream: bloc.tasks,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<UserTask>> tasks) {
            return new AppBar();/// my setup is here
          }),
```

but this is obviously doesn't compile.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`appBar` requires a widget that implements `PreferredSizeWidget`, and `StreamBuilder` isn't one.

You can wrap that tree into a `PreferredSize`:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: const Size(double.infinity, kToolbarHeight),
    child: // StreamBuilder
  ),
)
```

Comment: Works perfect for me.